# Rails unique attribute based on multiple columns Model view or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am building a rails app  that has users, and the users have skills, and the skills have many "skillsections" which belongs_to the user and has a single skill. Each skill section has a name value which is text.

I want to be able to force the skillsection name value to be unique **only** if it belongs to the same user and same skill.

So, if a user has a skill of "manager" I'd like them to be able to have a skillsection of "filling" for manager, but only once...and also allow them to have a second skill "paper shuffling" and a skillsection of filling there as well. To do so gracefully I need it not to be possible for the user to create a duplicated skillsection name for the same user and skill combination.

So, my question is: Where is the proper place to implement this according to MVC (database constraints through a migration or in the model.rb, or when the user submits the form?), and once that is determined, what is the approach?

```
irb(main):028:0> section = SkillSection.new
=> #<SkillSection id: nil, user_id: nil, skill_id: nil, name: nil, copy: nil, rank: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually add the uniqueness constraint in both model-level and database-level. To do in the model, you can use `scope` like this:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: [: user_id, : skill_id] }
```

Sometimes uniqueness validation in only model-level does not work as expected, so you should add constraint to the database too.  To do this, you can use a migration as follows:

```
add_index :skill_sections, [:name, :user_id, :skill_id], unique: true
```

You can check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness for more information.

You don't need to do anything in controller in this case. For more details about validations in Rails, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#why-use-validations-questionmark

Comment: Thank you Van Huy that is a very accurate and complete answer.